# What does it mean, "a contact has shot home"?

Tags: phrase-request

What does it mean? All Quiet On The Western Front

> We feel that in our blood **a contact has shot home**.

Comment: Out of context, can't guess. Please give the paragraph or two before this and any other relevant context from that point in the book

Comment: In the last AQotWF question I included two links to the English and German.  Make sure you include sufficient context.  Also try using autotranslate of the German text to English (or your native language) Sometimes that helps clarify the meaning.

Comment: To me, the words suggest that our gut reaction has been as if an electrical switch or relay had been activated.

Comment: Whose translation?

Comment: Wir fühlen, daß in unserm Blut ein Kontakt angeknipst ist.

Comment: My German isn't great, but I think the original refers to feeling like an electric switch is turned on. It's then translated into the English as "contact shot home," which doesn't have a lot of meaning in modern English. Maybe the old electric metaphor would have been translated this way 93 years ago; maybe I just misunderstand the German. In any case, I'm not sure there is a lot of English learning value to working through this bizarre and unfamiliar translated-into-English expression.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an error in translation.

Comment: "A circuit has closed" or "a circuit has been completed" would seem the usual translation today, but I'm reluctant to answer without a fuller question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wir fühlen, daß in unserm Blut ein Kontakt angeknipst
> ist - [Im Westen nichts Neues](https://ivannikovairina.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/remarque_im_westen_nichts_neues_pdf.pdf), p40

"shot home" is a bad translation. In the original German, the word used is **[anknipsen](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/anknipsen)**, which means "switch on".

The intended metaphor is that it feels like an electrical contact has switched on.

Answer (score 1):

"Contact" as in an electrical contact, or it may have a more specific meaning in military equipment (for example it might be when an explosive shell is made "live")

The sense is that the soldiers changed from relaxed to on-guard, as the first guns open fire above them.

Answer (score 1):

"Shot home" can refer to a bolt latch mechanism where the bolt is slid into a matching hole. The bolt is "shot home" when it is fully in the hole and so the latch is locked. The device is sometimes called a "shoot bolt", and examples can be seen at https://www.lockshopdirect.co.uk/categories/shoot-bolts-and-finger-bolts-16169.

The expression "shot home" would not normally be applied to an electrical switch (contact), but might be for certain types of switch.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context I cannot provide much more of an answer. However based on interpretation, it seems to mean that *something* has caused the "we" to feel in a way "hurt" (extremely), like the bullet has shot the exact place of the heart.